# SOAP XMl Serialization for property c#

Tags: xml, serialization, soap

Currently my soap is generated like this

```
 <HdrFault>
     <Fault>   
        <ConsumerProd>
           <Value>soa test</Value>
        </ConsumerProd>
     <Fault>
 </HrdFault>
```

I want it generated like this

```
<HdrFault>
   <Fault>   
      <ConsumerProd>soa test</ConsumerProd>
   <Fault>
</HrdFault>
```

This is the Business object. I understand why it has a 'Value' field in there.  How do I serialize this to have the above mentioned Soap XML?

```
[MessageContract]
public partial class HdrFault
{

    private FaultHdr_CType faultHdrField;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public FaultHdr_CType FaultHdr
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faultHdrField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faultHdrField = value;
        }
    }
}

[MessageContract]
public class FaultHdr_CType
{
    #region ConsumerProd

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public FaultConsumerProd_Type ConsumerProd { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

[MessageContract]
public class FaultConsumerProd_Type
{
    #region Value

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did two things to resolve the issue. 
Adding [XmlText]

```
  [MessageContract]
    public class ValidConsmName_Type
    {

        #region Value

         [XmlText]
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Secondly I added the following to the Contract

```
[XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]  
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://jackhenry.com/jxchange/TPG/2008")]
    public interface IInt
{
..}
```